# Natural ordering of varchar

Tags: mysql, varchar

I have 3 columns of varchar that I want to sort both numerically and alphabetically.  I want natural ordering as in 1, 2, 3 etc., but I also want the likes of 28A to come after 28 but before 29.  I've tried casting as signed asc, which gives me the natural ordering but also

```
28  1
28A 1
28  2
28A 2
28  3
28A 3
29
```

as opposed to what I want

```
28  1
28  2
28  3
28A 1
28A 2
28A 3
29
```

Appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ORDER BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html) like this

```
SELECT
 columna, columnb
FROM
  mytable
ORDER BY columna, columnb;
```

Comment: Got it working.  Instead of casting each column as signed asc I just did it for the first column.